Azure ML Query- No web service input generated and void input data schema during subsequent endpoint generation
I am trying to create real-time inference pipeline in azure ml , following all straight forward steps, but I am unable to generate the web service input . only web service output is generated.
Further, if I manually add web service input or add data manually, in the next steps to follow i.e. deployment to create endpoint, I am unable to get populated data schema in 'consume' section of endpoint because of which I am not able to run my prediction using input data. (If I had the data schema for input , I would create a notebook and run input there to get my prediction).

I have used all sorts of computes, including container instance, akscompute, checked my dataset thoroughly.
Desperate for any solution, I am so worked up because I have tried every possible solution .

Please do not post code screenshots - see how to create a [mre].

You need to send the data in a list, the content is on what column you trained and also how your scoring script accepts the data.
Example:
For below scoring script.
def init():
    global model
    global input_schema
    # "model" is the path of the mlflow artifacts when the model was registered. For automl
    # models, this is generally "mlflow-model".
    model_path = os.path.join(os.getenv("AZUREML_MODEL_DIR"), "model")
    model = mlflow.pyfunc.load_model(model_path)
    input_schema = model.metadata.get_input_schema()


def run(raw_data):
    json_data = json.loads(raw_data)
    if "input_data" not in json_data.keys():
        raise Exception("Request must contain a top level key named 'input_data'")

    serving_input = json.dumps(json_data["input_data"])
    data = infer_and_parse_json_input(serving_input, input_schema)
    predictions = model.predict(data)

    result = StringIO()
    predictions_to_json(predictions, result)
    return result.getvalue()

and for below trained dataset  columns.
"columns": [
      "age",
      "sex",
      "bmi",
      "bp",
      "s1",
      "s2",
      "s3",
      "s4",
      "s5",
      "s6"
    ]

the sample json input is.
{"input_data": {
    "columns": [
      "age",
      "sex",
      "bmi",
      "bp",
      "s1",
      "s2",
      "s3",
      "s4",
      "s5",
      "s6"
    ],
    "data": [
      [ 1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0 ],
      [ 10.0,2.0,9.0,8.0,7.0,6.0,5.0,4.0,3.0,2.0]
    ],
    "index": [0,1]
  }}

You can find scoring script in the output files of training component.

Not only scoring script you can find sample json file which should be given as input, but you also need to check scoring script what and all it accepts.
If you don't find any of the files scoring script or sample.json or schema.json.
You check you dataset for column trained and create an input like below.
{"data": [
 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 
 [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
]}

Go through the samples and scoring script given in this GitHub repository for more information
